# Date modified of an executable displays the first build date when building with cxfreeze. However the executable runs the most recent version

Tags: python, exe, cx-freeze

I built a simple python script as an exe file - first build didn't display expected results so I rebuilt it with changes, exe works fine now however the exe file is still displaying is original build date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cx_Freeze calls shutil.copystat() on all files that it copies, so the source time is used on the target file as well.